# Docker PULL stellar/quickstart error

Tags: stellar-laboratory

When I try pulling the Stellar image from the UNIX server with the command: '$docker pull stellar/quickstart' I get the error message : **Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.** What should I do to get the docker daemon running - or, can I 'pull' it from somewhere else? ...many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

type this command to check if your docker is running

> sudo systemctl status docker

output should look like this if it is running

> ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
>
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor p
>
> Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-07-02 11:28:40 UTC; 15min ago
>
> ```
> Docs: https://docs.docker.com
> ```
>
> Main PID: 11911 (dockerd)
>
> Tasks: 10
>      CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service